# Theorem on factorized distribution on a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I'm studying for an exam on Algorithms and Inference and I can't make sense of a mathematical step in a proof.

The theorem states:

> Let $P(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{Z}\prod_a \Psi_a (\mathbf{x}_a)$ be a
>   factorized distribution, where the bipartite factor graph of factors
>   $a$ and variables $i$ is a tree. Then
>
> $$P(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_a P_a(\mathbf{x}_a) \prod_i P(x_i)^{1-n_i}=
>  \prod_a \frac{P_a(\mathbf{x}_a)}{\prod_{i \in \partial a}P(x_i)}
>  \prod_i P(x_i)$$
>
> where $n_i$ is the degree of vertex i.

$P(x_i)$ is the marginal distribution of $x_i$

$P_a(\mathbf{x}_a)=\frac{1}{Z} \Psi_a (\mathbf{x}_a)$

The **proof** goes like this:

The result is valid for a tree with one vertex. In this case the product over $i$ is equal to 1 and the product over $a$ has only one term.

We proceed by induction on the number of nodes in the factor
graph. If $x_i$ is a leaf (connected to $b$), $n_i = 1$, then:

\begin{align}P(\mathbf{x}\setminus\{x_i\}) &= \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{x_i}\prod_a \Psi_a (\mathbf{x}_a)\\
&= \frac{1}{Z} \left ( \sum_{x_i} \Psi_b (\mathbf{x}_b)\right)\prod_{a \neq b} \Psi_a (\mathbf{x}_a)\\
&= \prod_{a \neq b} P(\mathbf{x}_a) P(\mathbf{x}_b \setminus \{x_i \})\prod_{j \neq i} P(\mathbf{x}_j)^{1-n_j}
\end{align}

Now, the first passage is clear: isolate the function which depends on $x_i$. The last passage is justified by "induction hypothesis" in my notes, but I don't understand it. The proof ends using some identities on conditional probabilities to get the statement of the theorem.

So to make the question clear: how do I go from

$$\frac{1}{Z} \left ( \sum_{x_i} \Psi_b (\mathbf{x}_b)\right)\prod_{a \neq b} \Psi_a (\mathbf{x}_a)$$

to

$$\prod_{a \neq b} P(\mathbf{x}_a) P(\mathbf{x}_b \setminus \{x_i \})\prod_{j \neq i} P(\mathbf{x}_j)^{1-n_j}$$
?

Comment: In your first set of displayed equations, when you write $x_i$ under the sum, what does that mean?  The notation is confusing for two reasons: (1) The variable $i$ seems to be a free variable on the left side of the equation, and (part of) an index of summation on the right; (2) There are no $i$'s in the expression inside the summation.

Comment: I forgot an $x_$ in front of it. It's the variable over which I'm doing the marginalization. And I also should clarify that $\mathbf{x}_a$ are subsets of $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: Of course I mean $x_i$ is the variable over which I'm doing the marginalization

Comment: So $i$ is fixed?  Then what are you summing over?

Comment: I'm summing over $x_i$ to find the distribution of $\mathbf{x} \setminus x_i = \left ( x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n \right )$. Also, $\mathbf{x}_a$ are subsets of $\mathbf{x}$ and $x_i$ is in one of these subsets, namely $\mathbf{x}_b$